# How to connect an oracle DB with MySQL workbench?

Tags: oracle, mysql-workbench, connectivity

I am a bit confused:
I want to connect an Oracle DB with the application "MySQL Workbench". In order its from Oracle as well I throught that this is possible. But until now Im not able to do so.

With the "Oracle SQL Developer" is it working, so my credentials have to be correct.

Is it just impossible to connect an oracle db with mysql workbench?

kind regards
mario

Answer (score 4):

to answer your question:

"Thanks for your answers. I thought not that oracle own this product they made it able to connect to a oracle database. Is there a semilar tool like workbench for oracle dbs?" from comments,

you can use toad for oracle or even sql developer.

Answer (score 3):

SQLDeveloper can access a MYSQL database contrary to an earlier post:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/mysql-connection-viewlet-swf-085075.html

But that's not what's being asked here.  The suggestion to just use SQLDeveloper is not too usefull if 98% of your tables are in MYSQL and you need to join to the 2% that are in Oracle, as is my case.  It looks like you're just out of luck if you need to access Oracle database FROM MYSQL workbench or command line.